# Search and delete in double linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, delete-operator

I want to search something in a double linked list and delete it.

My problem is that I lose both previous and the node of the node I want to delete.

Here is my code:

```
    int delnode(string moviename)
        {
            node *temp,*del;
            //check empty
            if(!head)
                {
                    cout<<"empty";
                }
            else
                {
                    temp=head;
                while (temp->next!=NULL)
                    {

                        if (temp->title==moviename)
                            {
                                del=temp;
                                temp=temp->previous;
                                temp->next=del->next;
                                delete del;
                            }
                        temp=temp->next;
                    }
                }
        }
```

For example if I have 5 movies, movie1,movie2,movie3,movie4,movie5 and want to delete movie3 my list will be movie1,movie4,movie5 :S

Comment: Consider separating the two operations into separate functions.  Make a find that takes a movie name and returns a pointer to the node.  Make a separate function that takes a pointer to the node and deletes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this incredibly hard on yourself. Your code has a number of problems, including:

- failure to properly wire the previous pointers
- failure to account for a last-node deletion.
- failure to advance the head pointer if it was the prospect node.

Considering that, I think this does what you want, and I *strongly* advise you to examine it carefully, even stepping through it in a debugger to see how it works.

```
void delnode(const std::string& moviename)
{
    // pp holds the address of the pointer that will
    //  eventually point to our node being deleted.
    node **pp = &head;

    // skip nodes until we find a match
    while (*pp && (*pp)->title.compare(moviename))
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    if (*pp)
    {
        node *tmp = *pp;
        if ((*pp = tmp->next)) // assignment-eval intentional
            (*pp)->previous = tmp->previous;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

This solves a number of issues, including

- properly updating the head pointer if it was the node matching your string.
- properly wiring `next` and `previous` to all proper pointers
- properly removing the *last* node in the list if that is your suspect node.
- doing absolutely nothing if the head pointer is null.

Comment: This is working perfect, i just need some time to understand it :D
Thanks!

Comment: @DeviLFisH you need to *seriously* understand how pointers work. Above all remember this: a pointer is nothing more than a variable that *holds* the address of someplace that contains the data type of the pointer. *And this is true for pointers-to-pointers as well.*. Ex: Given `int a, *p=&a;` `p` holds the address of `a`, an `int` variable. Now consider this: `int a, *p=&a, **pp=&p;` As before, `p` holds the address of `a`. And  in *exactly* the same way, `pp` holds the address of `p`. Getting a grip on that will really help you understand this code.

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating the `previous` link on what is `temp->next` at the end of it all.

You need to add in `temp->next->previous = temp` just before the `delete del` line, since you're using a double linked list.

Comment: I add "temp->next->previous = temp" before delete, but i have the same result

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

If your list only has one item, you'll never test it because of

```
if ( temp->next != NULL )
```

If your item is at the head of the list that you want to delete, you don't update head and you're code will crash anyways because you don't test that temp->previous is valid.

And if you delete an item, you don't update the back pointer as @Leigh mentioned.

Here is my unlink an item code from my list template:

```
void    untie_pointer( _Tp * aptr )
{
    if ( aptr )
    {
        if ( aptr-> prior() ) { aptr-> prev_-> next_= aptr-> next_ ; }
            else { if ( first_ == aptr ) { first_= aptr-> next_ ;  if (first_) { first_-> pr
ev_= nullptr ; } } }
        aptr -> prev_= nullptr ;
        if ( aptr-> next() ) { aptr-> next_-> prev_= aptr-> prev_ ; }
            else { if ( last_ == aptr ) { last_= aptr-> prev_ ;  if ( last_ ) { last_-> next
_= nullptr ; } } }
        aptr-> next_= nullptr ;
    }
}
```

Its because of all these cases that the gcc stl list uses a sentinel object.

Comment: what i noticed when looking at your code snippet is that how ugly it looks when you make your variables with underscore `_` and use it with object pointer dereferencing with `->`

Comment: It is, but since its internal private implementation code, hopefully nobody will ever have to look at it.

Comment: yes, same as stl source code. But providing it in an answer should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I wrote to check if the node

1.is in the front and no nodes after it.

2.is in the front and have nodes after it.

3.the node is the last node

4.a node is in the nth position

```
void deleteRear()
{
if(n == NULL)
{
cout <<"No People Found" << endl;
}
else
{
node *temp1;
if(n == NULL)
{
cout<<"No People Found"<<endl;
}
else
{
temp1 = start_ptr;
if(temp1->prev == NULL && temp1->nxt == NULL)
{
start_ptr = NULL;
delete temp1;
n = NULL;
}
else
{
while (temp1->nxt != NULL)
{
temp1 = temp1->nxt;
end_ptr= temp1->prev;
}
end_ptr->nxt = NULL;
delete temp1;
cout<<end_ptr->name<<endl;  
}
}
}   
}
void deleteAPerson()
{
if(n == NULL)
{
cout <<"No People Found" << endl;
}
else
{
node *temp1;
temp1 = start_ptr;
while(temp1 != NULL)
{
cout << "Name : " << temp1->name << endl;

temp1 = temp1 ->nxt;
}
node *temp, *temp2, *temp3, *temp4;
temp = start_ptr;
string names; 
cout << "Please Enter Person's Name: >>";
cin >> names;
while(temp->nxt != NULL && temp->name != names)
{
temp = temp->nxt;   
}
if (temp->name == names)
{
if(temp->prev == NULL && temp->nxt == NULL)
{
cout<<"Deleting Front"<<endl;
cout<<"Only one person on the list"<<endl;
temp = start_ptr;
start_ptr = NULL;
delete temp;
n = NULL;
}
else if (temp->prev == NULL && temp->nxt != NULL)
{
cout<<"Deleting Front"<<endl;
cout<<"There are other people on the list"<<endl;
temp2 = start_ptr;
start_ptr = start_ptr->nxt;
start_ptr->prev = NULL;
delete temp2;
}
else if(temp->prev != NULL && temp->nxt == NULL)
{
cout<<"Deleting End"<<endl;
deleteRear();
}
else
{
current = temp;
current->prev->nxt = current->nxt;
current->nxt->prev = current->prev;
delete current;
}
}
else
{
cout<<"No such person exists"<<endl;
}
}
}
```